# Setting minOccurs=0 in a WSDL using "Specified" pattern not working

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

OK, obviously I'm doing something wrong here.  I'm trying to create a webservice and I want "dateShipped" to be optional which means in the WSDL, I want minOccurs="0"

```
[Serializable]
[XmlType]
public class CTShipment
{
    [XmlElement(Order = 0, IsNullable=false)] public CTDeliveryMethod DeliveryMethod;
    [XmlElement(Order = 1, IsNullable=false)] public CTShipmentAddress ShipmentAddress;
    [XmlIgnore] public bool dateShippedSpecified;
    [XmlElement(Order = 2, IsNullable=false)] public DateTime dateShipped;
}
```

I want the WSDL to be generated like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="CTShipment">
  <xs:annotation>
     <xs:documentation>All details for the shipment of a suborder.</xs:documentation>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="DeliveryMethod" type="CTDeliveryMethod" nillable="false"/>
     <xs:element name="ShipmentAddress" type="CTShipmentAddress" nillable="false"/>
     <xs:element name="dateShipped" type="xs:dateTime" nillable="false" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Instead what I am actually getting is this:

```
<xs:complexType name="CTShipment">
  <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="DeliveryMethod" nillable="true" type="tns:CTDeliveryMethod"/>
     <xs:element name="ShipmentAddress" nillable="true" type="tns:CTShipmentAddress"/>
     <xs:element name="dateShipped" type="xs:dateTime"/>
     <xs:element name="dateShippedSpecified" type="xs:boolean"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

According to several things I've read (including http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds0b35c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) including the public bool "dateShippedSpecified" should make "dateShipped" optional (minOccurs=0).  As you can see, not only is this not happening but "dateShippedSpecified" is showing up in the WSDL even though it is marked with "[XmlIgnore]".  You may have noticed that there is another problem as well: even though I'm specifying "IsNullable=false", I still get nillable="true" in the WSDL.

That is no less than 4 problems I can't explain all related to the same thing:

1. How can I set minOccurs to 0 in my WSDL?
2. Why isn't the [fieldName]Specified pattern making [fieldName] optional (minOccurs = 0)?
3. Even if it wasn't following the ___Specified pattern, why would dateShippedSpecified show up in the WSDL if it is marked with XmlIgnore?
4. Why is everything marked as nillable="true" even though I'm specifying "IsNullable=false"?

   and as a bonus question, if anyone knows...
5. How do I get the annotation (as shown below) to be included?

   ```
   <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>All details for the shipment of a suborder.</xs:documentation>
   </xs:annotation>
   ```

Comment: For the record, I've moved away from the XML Serializer and am now using the Data Contract Serializer.  I can set minOccurs so I'm able to move forward with my project, but I am still curious about what was going on with the XML Serializer, if anyone knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to Sequence element. It specifies that every element has minOccurs= 1.
And the WSDL uses a Sequence-Element instead of "All" because you specified an Order to them.
This requires that every value is present.

So it should work allready when you remove the Order. If you really need the order, than there is no way for you to leave out that value.

Comment: As noted above, I am no longer using the XML serializer, so I haven't been able to test this answer out.  However, it makes sense and looks like it would answer most of my questions. I am marking this as the answer so that the question no longer appears open.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in .net implementation.

According to W3C specs (for wsdl) minOccurs="0" can be used within sequence. "< sequence >" 
means elements in order occurring 0 or more times.

For example look at official W3C definition of wsdl: http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl

You will see elements like:

```
<sequence>
         <element ref="wsdl:documentation" minOccurs="0"/>
 </sequence>
```

For now when need to be .Net compatible use nillable="true"
which will give you DateTime? (nullable version) instead of DateTime.